# What is the maximum throughput or upload limit on the amount of simultaneous data being transferred using an Azure IRT?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

Is there a maximum throughput or upload limit on the amount of simultaneous data being transferred using an Azure IRT as part of an Azure data factory before a pipeline and/or activity may timeout or fail?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The answer is ***we cannot tell***.

There is an interesting article about [Hyperscale throughput](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/how-fast-can-a-5436-mo-azure-sql-db-hyperscale-load-data/) and most of the research I did around throughput they don't give me a concrete answer.

On the same article you can find a comment that states:

> Dont’t bother with Azure Data Factory. For some reason with type
> casting from blob to Azure SQL, but also Azure SQL Database as a
> source, the throughput is dramatic. From 6 MB/s to 13 MB/s on high
> service tiers for transferring 1 table, 5GB in total. That is beyond
> bad.

[image]

So there are too many factor to count in: where the data come from, where the data go, the products you are using, etc...

You might need to open a (paid) ticket with Azure support and ask if they hardcoded that trigs a timeout. But in my experience I've seen simple database migration from SQL Server to Azure SQL DB failing for no reason and then complete at a second try.